# Read PDF in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Read PDF in Rails Application.**

My Application is in `RAILS 4` and I want to read PDF in my application. I don't want to download PDF. I Upload PDF and view in my application.

How it is possible or How can i do this?

Help Me Please...

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PDF reader gem.  https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader. It allows you to read over the web via a URL.

For example:

```
def count_words_in_pdf_file(filepath)
    io = filepath.start_with?('http') ? open(filepath) : filepath
    reader = PDF::Reader.new(io)
    total_count = 0
    if reader
      reader.pages.each do |page|
        total_count += count_words_in_text(page.text)
      end
    end
    total_count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to show PDF to users.

As a solution you could use [FancyBox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to display PDF in the frame:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf">Test pdf</a>

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    iframe : {
        preload: false
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RHaAX/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `send_data` method

```
def view_pdf
  File.open("path/to/pdf", 'rb') do |f|
    send_data f.read, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "inline"
  end
end
```

but the user's browser can override and download the pdf anyway.

If you want  force the pdf viewing, can you use pdf.js created by mozilla

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js